# Prove $\{(u^3,u^2v,uv^2,v^3)\mid u,v\in\mathbb C\}$ is an algebraic set.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

I have to prove that $V=\{(u^3,u^2v,uv^2,v^3)\mid u,v\in\mathbb C\}$ is an algebraic set. How can I find an ideal $I\leq \mathbb C[x,y,z,t]$ s.t. $$V=Z(I)=\{(x,y,z,t)\in \mathbb C^4\mid \forall f\in I, f(x,y,z,t)=0\}\ \ ?$$

I really have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to find polynomial relations satisfied by $x = u^3, y= u^2v, z = uv^2, t = v^3$.  For instance, since
$$
xt = u^3 v^3 = u^2 v \cdot u v^2 = yz
$$
then one such relation is $xt - yz = 0$.  There should be two more, both degree $2$ like this one: see if you can find them.

> The other two quadrics are $x z - y^2$ and $yt - z^2$.

If you want a general systematic way of finding implicit equations for a parametrization, you can use [Gröbner bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis).  This is discussed in $\S3.3$: Implicitization of Cox, Little, and O'Shea's *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms*.  [See this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491869/veronese-surface-represented-by-an-intersection-of-quadratics) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your very constructive answer. Can't be better ! :)