# Algebraic representation and parametric rapresentation

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Does it exist a general algorithm to find the algebraic representation of an affine subspace starting from the parametric rapresentation?

Comment: I'm not confident that is a general algorithm to determine if an algebraic representation exists given a parametric one. Do you know a priori that the curves are algebraic?

Comment: If you mean a polynomial or rational parametrization, then yes, there is such an algorithm.  This topic (implicitization) is covered in Cox, Little, O'Shea.  I mention the relevant theorem in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491869/veronese-surface-represented-by-an-intersection-of-quadratics).